# symfony2.7, bloodhound, typeahead not showing autocomplete

Tags: symfony, typeahead.js, bloodhound

i'm trying to use typeahead with symfony 2.7 for database search using LIKE. I've read the documentation for typeahead and based on the examples from their website i put togther a small example to see how it works. Since i have about 1300 entries in the table where i perform search i generated a json file with all the entries for performance.
The problem is that typeahead doesn't show any info from remote or from prefetch and i don't understand why it doesn't work because i didn't make too many changes to the original code from the examples. For the moment the generated result contains dummy data from the examples page because i was thinking there is something wrong with the results returned from remote. Maybe i'm missing something and i can't see the solution.
I checked the console and i don't get any errors, bloodhound is loaded before typeahead both are loaded fine and the js file is loaded after them and it shows the content.

Javascript File:

```
    var url = Routing.generate('ajax_search', {name: 'query'});
// Trigger typeahead + bloodhound
var products = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '/json/result.json',
     remote: {
      url: url,
      wildcard: 'query'
    }
});

products.initialize();

$('#products_forms .typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'product',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: products.ttAdapter()
});
```

the html test file

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="col-sm-10" id="product">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Product" id="product" name="product" class="form-control typeahead">
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

The dummy file generated from php

```
cat result.json

            {"stateCode": "CA", "stateName": "California"},
            {"stateCode": "AZ", "stateName": "Arizona"},
            {"stateCode": "NY", "stateName": "New York"},
            {"stateCode": "NV", "stateName": "Nevada"},
            {"stateCode": "OH", "stateName": "Ohio"}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems it works like this:

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = Routing.generate('ajax_search', {name: 'WILDCARD'});
    // Trigger typeahead + bloodhound
    var products = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        identify: function(obj) { return obj.team; },
        prefetch: 'json/result.json',
        remote: {
          url: url,
          wildcard: 'WILDCARD',
        }
    });

    products.initialize();

    $('#products_forms .typeahead').typeahead({
      minLength: 3,
      highlight: true
    },
    {
      name: 'product',
      display: 'team',
      source: products.ttAdapter()
    });
});
```